# Grouping with usort function

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, grouping, usort

I need to sort tags. Each tag looks like this "Firstname Lastname (University)".
I want the names to be sorted by university, then echoed like this:

**University1:**
Firstname1 Lastname1 (University1)
Firstname2 Lastname2 (University1)
etc.

**University2:**
Firstname3 Lastname3 (University2)
Firstname4 Lastname4 (University2)
etc.

**University3:**
Firstname5 Lastname5 (University3)
Firstname6 Lastname6 (University3)
etc.

I managed to sort through them, then echo the whole list, but I can't figure out how to group the results.

Here is my code:

```
function compareUniversity($a, $b) {
    $matchA = [];
    $matchB = [];
    preg_match('/\(([\w]+)\)/', $a->name, $matchA);
    preg_match('/\(([\w]+)\)/', $b->name, $matchB);
    $aUniversity = $matchA[1];
    $bUniversity = $matchB[1];
    return strcmp($aUniversity, $bUniversity);
};

usort($tags, "compareUniversity");

echo '<ul>';

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $term = $tag->term_id;
        $st= 'post_tag_'.$term;

        $link = get_field('url',$st, true);

   echo '<li><a href="http://'.$link.'" target="_blank">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce` to group the array.

```
//Sample array
$tags = array(
    'Firstname1 Lastname1 (University1)',
    'Firstname2 Lastname2 (University1)',
    'Firstname3 Lastname3 (University2)',
    'Firstname4 Lastname4 (University2)',
    'Firstname5 Lastname5 (University3)',
    'Firstname6 Lastname6 (University3)'
);

//Group array
$orderedTags = array_reduce($tags, function($c, $v){
    preg_match('/\(([\w]+)\)/', $v, $u);
    $c[ $u[1] ][] = $v;
    return $c;
}, array());


//Print Grouped array
echo '<ul>';
foreach( $orderedTags as $key => $orderedTag ) {
    echo "<li>" . $key . "</li>";

    //Loop each tags
    echo "<li>";
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $orderedTag as $item ) {
            echo "<li>" . $item . "</li>";
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    echo "</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

This will result to:

```html
<ul>
  <li>University1</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Firstname1 Lastname1 (University1)</li>
      <li>Firstname2 Lastname2 (University1)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>University2</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Firstname3 Lastname3 (University2)</li>
      <li>Firstname4 Lastname4 (University2)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>University3</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Firstname5 Lastname5 (University3)</li>
      <li>Firstname6 Lastname6 (University3)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

As per [Wordpress doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/), you can use `get_the_tags();` to get the tags.

Note: This is not tested on wordpress. Please let me know if this works.

```
$tags = get_the_tags($post->ID); //Get tag from wordpress

//Try to print_r
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $tags );
echo "</pre>";

//Group array
$orderedTags = array_reduce($tags, function($c, $v){
    $v = $v->name;
    preg_match('/\(([\w]+)\)/', $v, $u);
    $c[ $u[1] ][] = $v;
    return $c;
}, array());


//Print Grouped array
echo '<ul>';
foreach( $orderedTags as $key => $orderedTag ) {
    echo "<li>" . $key . "</li>";

    //Loop each tags
    echo "<li>";
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $orderedTag as $item ) {
            echo "<li>" . $item . "</li>";
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    echo "</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! This works great, the only thing is that the names are not fixed, it's all the tags that are and will be added through wordpress. Which means that I need something like: $tags = array(
[dynamic way of calling all the tags here]
); I tried with get_tags but can't seem to make it work. Thanks again!

Comment: Ohh.. I thought your problem is grouping tags.. I assumed that you already have tags. Are you able to get the tags by `get_tags`?

Comment: According to wordpress doc, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/ you can use `get_the_tags();`

Comment: Your added code is what I had tried already and it doesn't get the tags for some reason. Which is weird because I use the same get_the_tags($post->ID) function later on in my code for something else, and it works then

Comment: Can you post a `print_r` or `var_dump` of `get_the_tags($post->ID)`

Comment: it says: array(0) { }

Comment: You are not getting it. You might wanna check on how to get it first.

Comment: Ok, I'll work on that. Thank you so much for your help though, I'm sure I'll figure it out! Thank you x1000

Comment: Oh, $tags = get_tags(array('hide_empty' => false, 'order'=>'ASC')); works! :))))) Thank you again!

Comment: Ohh, Great to hear! Happy to help :)